# WAR hazard causes bubbles in the pipeline (MIPS)?

Tags: assembly, mips, cpu-architecture

If I have 2 lines of assembly like:

```
add $s1, $s3, $s5 
sub $s3, $s6, $s8
```

this should cause a WAR (write after read) hazard, correct?

The problem is that I do not understand if it will cause the insertion of bubbles in the pipeline since I have to draw the pipeline table.

Is there any different case when this can cause a hazard or not?

Comment: How many stages are in your pipeline? If there are 5 stages, this is not a hazard.

Comment: yes, this is a 5 stage pipeline (fetch, decode, read, execute, write). so no bubbles needed?

Comment: This is indeed an anti-dependency, but in the classic pipeline that does not create a hazard. That read happens really early and that write really late, there's no problem there.

Comment: @GiacomoBenso Welcome to Stack Overflow, by the way. Please let me know if I haven't addressed your concern, otherwise you can upvote and / or accept my answer.

Comment: @IRTFM: the [cpu-architecture] tag covers stuff like data hazards in a pipeline.  If you're fixing misuse of the [hazard] tag in other questions, add that if it's not already present.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> WAR hazard is uncommon/impossible in a reasonable (in-order)
>   pipeline

[Pipeline Hazards, Page 2](http://cseweb.ucsd.edu/classes/wi05/cse240a/pipe2.pdf)

Here's a table to demonstrate why, in a 5-stage pipelined CPU. Let's label them instructions 1 and 2.

```
 IF | ID | EX | MEM | WB
-------------------------
 1  |    |    |     |
-------------------------
 2  |(1) |    |     |     Instruction 1 is obtaining $s3
-------------------------
    | 2  | 1  |     |    
-------------------------
    |    | 2  |  1  |
-------------------------
    |    |    |  2  | 1
-------------------------
    |    |    |     |(2)  Instruction 2 is writing $s3 back
```

Instructions obtain operands from the register file during the ID (Instruction Decode) stage, but the result isn't written back to the register file until the WB (write-back) stage. Instruction 1 is in the ID stage 4 clock cycles before instruction 2 is in the WB stage, so there is no possibility of `$s3` being overwritten before it is used.